# Different style on menu points, when menu is collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap nav-bar, which collapses into a button, totally default.

In my nav-bar, I have a bunch of images, instead of text links. When the bar is collapsed, I would like these pictures to be smaller.

Is there any way to style my way out of this?

Can I give it another menu to use, when it's collapsed?

Example code (default Bootstrap):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#FlagMenu">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Select plant</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="FlagMenu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <img src="~/Content/imgs/Flag_Dansk.png" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="~/Content/imgs/Flag_Tjekkisk.png" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="~/Content/imgs/Flag_Mexikansk.png" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="~/Content/imgs/Flag_Ungarsk.png" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="~/Content/imgs/Flag_China.png" />
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: add some code or jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite parts of media queries styles of bootstrap by adding your own class to html-structure where you define styles (width, height, etc.) for the images.

Comment: If I understand you right you need to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5896/